# P-value for t-score

Tags: t-test, p-value

With a z-score you can look-up the p-value (percentage) in a table. For t-scores you just get a table to look up the t-score for your desired alpha level given the degrees of freedom you have. You can compare that score with your t-score but what if you wanted a p-value instead?

Comment: This is where statistical software like R, Python, SAS, Stata, and SPSS come in (I prefer the first two). Excel might even have some tools like “pt” in R. But I think this gets at how the reject/not methodology came to be 100 years ago when they had to make decisions based on tables like you have and couldn’t calculate the p-value on a computer. They either landed above or below the specified threshold.

Comment: @Dave Your history seems a little skewed.  The standard tools for many centuries (at least four) were tables and interpolation techniques.  That was the basis for computing t-statistic p-values until computers started becoming more accessible to researchers (in the 1960's) and everyone else (in the late 1980's). A great many "numerical quadrature" techniques were also in vogue and used by engineers and mathematicians working with pencil and paper (or adding machines). The cumulative Student t distributions are particularly amenable to numerical integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: ask a machine.

Say your t-statistic is 2.14 on 39 degrees of freedom.

The table probably gives you t for conventional values of alpha (here, three of them). They're called 'p' in R's quantile function for the t-distribution, `qt`

```
alphas <- c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05)

qt(p = alphas, df = 39, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 3.312788 2.425841 1.684875
```

whereas you want 'p' from a particular value of t. You can get it from R's t-distribution CDF function, `pt`.

```
pt(2.14, df = 39, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.01933356
```

Set 'p' to 0.01933356 in `qt` to recover 2.14